# UITextField + secureTextEntry. Unmask character that was just typed temporarily?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I'm using UITextField + secureTextEntry for capturing a password. Is there a property in the SDK that lets me show just the character that was just typed in for around half a second and then mask it? I'm looking for something that is similar to what Apple does in all their default apps like the Appstore etc.

I didn't find anything relating to this in the docs themselves. How should I handle this if I need to build it myself? I can think of an ugly way where we'd temporarily add another UITextField over the existing textfield and show the character within it, but there's probably a simpler way?

Thanks, 
Teja

Answer (score 1):

UITextField.secureTextEntry = YES should just work.

Comment: with secureTextEntry, I don't see the character being temporarily visible. It just puts the * in the text field directly?

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, I'm making a custom keyboard and not using the default iOS one. Maybe that has something to do with it. I'm setting the text using setText method of the UITextField ?